# Java: Why use with methods instead of constructor?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Say you have a class called `Person`, and a `Person` has attributes such as `name`, `id`, `age`, etc. Instead of setting these values in the constructor, one does

```
new Person().withName("Lorem").withId("1234").withAge(29)
```

Where a `with` method is a call to a `set` method, and returns the object, e.g.,

```
public Person withAge(int age) {
    this.setAge(age);
    return this;
}
```

On a current project, I see a lot of code like this, often with 5-10 chained calls to different `with` methods. What are the benefits of doing this instead of setting these values in the constructor?

Comment: That some sort of a Builder, never so that specific pattern but if you have to many optionnal value, I guess this could be a good idea. (PS : You forgot the return statement in the `withAge`)

Comment: The code is more readable: new Person("a", "b", "c") doesn't easily indicate what a, b and c are.

Comment: If I look at your code, I can see where you're setting up the name, the ID, and the age.  If I see `new Person("Lorem", "1234", 29)`, I don't get that info.  If Java allowed named parameters the way some other languages do (like C# and Swift), there would be less need for this kind of chaining.  That is my #1 complaint about Java, and I'm not quite certain why there hasn't been any move to add this feature, that I can see.

Comment: may be if you need to set only 1feature of a person in one class and 2 features in other class then you will have to define two constructors with different arguments(which will lead to multiple constructors with multiple arguments).so to avoid this problem you can set your values directly by using setters methods..I am not sure

Comment: By the way, Java doesn't allow strings in single quote marks :)

Comment: Well, it isn't JavaScript since it uses `public` and `int` keywords.

Comment: @ajb and they invented kotlin :-)

Comment: it should be `public Person withAge` if you return **this**

Comment: @JBNizet Use IDEA, it provides parameter hints

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov The hints are helpful, but that does not excuse one from writing code in a more readable manner.  Where I work, a lot of us use IntelliJ, but there are those who use Eclipse, and we also have ways to look at other teams' code in a browser without downloading it into an IDE.  So it is not good enough to write code that's harder to understand, and count on everybody else using IntelliJ to understand it.  That doesn't work.

Comment: @JBNizet I prefer to use a sane IDE instead of cluttering the code with meaningless setters

Comment: Its all about readability and [fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov "_with meaningless setters_" when those can save you time during a debugging phase, you will notice that this is not that meaningless. Especially on critical application where you can be ask to do some maintenance at any time, you don't necessarly have access to your workstation, but you could still access a remote versionning system to access an understand the code without the need of an IDE. PS : Unless you never used `setXXX`, you agreed with that concept too, just not with that unknown pattern.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I'm not saying I would do that (although it can be handy sometimes). I generally prefer immutable classes. I'm just explaining what the advantage over a constructor is, that's all. There are obviously disadvantages, too. And I use IntelliJ, BTW, but would still prefer named parameters as Kotlin has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage i see is readability.

If we extend the example

```
new Person()
.withName("Lorem")
.withId("1234")
.withAge(29)
.withHeight(170)
.withWeight(75)
.withTaxId("1234");
```

If we didn't use this pattern and used the constructor pattern we would end up lots of parameter without any description about them when using them.

```
new Person("Lorem","1234",29,170,75,"1234");
```

Answer (score 3):

> What are the benefits of doing this instead of setting these values in the constructor?

**1) Overloading**

You can manage the number of value you want to set easily, if you have a lot of parameter to set, but some are optionnal, you don't have to create specific constructor or passing `null` value.

```
 new Person("name", 19);
 new Person("name", 19, address);

 new Person("name", 19, phone);
```

(those are bad example ;) )

In you case, you just have to call the method you need (**same with setters**).

**2) Identitication**

Also, having a lot of parameters in a method/constructor tend to be difficult to read, to identify each parameter context

```
 new Person("frank", "John", "Emma");
 person.withName("frank").withFather("john").withMother("Emma");
```

Passing parameter to a method/constructor is nameless, you have to check the signature to understand what you are passing. With that notation, you have a more verbose and readable code. (**again, same with setters**).

**3) Chainable setter** 
The same would be done with setters but without the chainable feature you have here.

```
person.setName("name");
person.setAge(19);

person.withName("name").withAge(19);
```

---

Other than the readability, I don't think there is really some improvement, the chain need the method to return the instance itself, **that give a redondant code in the class itself** (`return this;`).

Comment: I agree, I never understood why this method chaining is so hyped.

Answer (score 2):

Its all about readability and [fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

While your example is not a very good one for fluent interfaces, you can find on in the [Java part of the wikipedia article:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java):

```
Author author = AUTHOR.as("author");
create.selectFrom(author)
      .where(exists(selectOne()
                   .from(BOOK)
                   .where(BOOK.STATUS.eq(BOOK_STATUS.SOLD_OUT))
                   .and(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID.eq(author.ID))));
```

---

Fluent interfacing is a very advanced topic in the API design, that often comes with some kind of [Builder pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/builder_pattern.htm) ([to avoid too big and too many constructors](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html)) or [Facade pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/facade_pattern.htm) (to avoid hard to understand, mostly internal APIs).

A *pretty* fluent API normally require a deep understanding of your requirements and a very good planning/preparation phase.

---

Note that using fluent APIs is closely connected to writing a DSL. Here you have an example by [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) and an extended, [really good explanation](https://jaxenter.de/java-8-stream-api-codegenerierung-mit-fluent-interfaces-9159) of fluent interfacing, its advantages, disadvantages, theories, etc.

Comment: Here it is, I knew I had seen that notation somewhere !

Comment: @AxelH yeh, I added some details - didnt think the answer would still get much of attention, so I did not put too much effort in it at first

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be 2 major advantages :

1.) Flexibility : With this pattern, you can basically choose fields to populate and not populate. While with constructors, you need to have multiple constructors to achieve the same. As in `Person` can be

```
new Person().withName("Loren")
```

Or it can be

```
new Person().withName("Loren").withAge(30)
```

with everything else null/default.

In case of constructor initialization, you had to have 2 constructors for both of these.

```
public Person(String name){
  //code
}

public Person(String name, String age){
//code
}
```

2.) As mentioned by other answers, readability.

```
new Person().withName("Loren").withAge(30).withId(567)
```

is more readable than

```
new Person("Loren", 30, 567)
```